# Xamarin.Forms: UI Test Error

Tags: user-interface, xamarin.android

I'm trying to do UI tests in a Xamarin Android app. Currently I'm stuck with this error (please check the link attached)

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103891/xamarin-android-ui-test-error/p1?new=1

**UPDATE**

Here's a link to my recent question. Please check this out to understand what I mean and some things I noticed/encountered during the testing I performed.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60050

Answer (score 0):

You can try reinstalling the android apk. Can you provide your code for your tests?

Answer (score 0):

Clean and recompile the solution, it should work.

Comment: Are you trying to test it on debug mode? or you are releasing the app to apk to test the version?